# How to dynamically replace custom tags of a string?

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have the following string saved in one of my MSSQL tables:

```
"Inflicts [regular damage]{mechanic:regular-damage}."
```

I want to replace everything inside [] for a link pointing to mechanic:regular-damage, like this:

```
"Inflicts <a href=\"/Mechanics.aspx?Name=regular-damage\">regular damage</a>."
```

How could I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything. Regex, String ops etc.

Comment: @EZI I tried regex, but I've failed miserably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture three things - the content of square brackets, the content of curly braces prior to the colon, and the rest of the content of curly braces. You can do it using this regex:

```
@"\[([^\]]+)\]{([^:]+):([^}]+)}"
//  ^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^
//  Group$1    Group$2 Group$3
```

With these three groups captured, you can format the answer using this replacement template:

```
@"<a href=""$2.aspx?Name=$3"">$1</a>"
```

Putting it all together, you get

```
var s = @"Inflicts [regular damage]{mechanic:regular-damage}.";
var r = Regex.Replace(
    s
,   @"\[([^\]]+)\]{([^:]+):([^}]+)}"
,   @"<a href=""$2.aspx?Name=$3"">$1</a>"
);
```

This produces

```
Inflicts <a href="mechanic.aspx?Name=regular-damage">regular damage</a>.
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/ca7LAL)